# Oracle Sql update command

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update cds set numberinstock=numberinstock+3 order by cdname asc
```

i am using above update command in oracle but it is giving error SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: an `order by` in an `update` statement does not make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to update the column in ascending order in cdname ,this command is working in mysql but not in Oracle

Comment: "*update the column in ascending order in cdname*" does not make any sense either. You don't "update in a certain order". You update. And just because MySQL accepts a statement doesn't mean the statement makes sense in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot combine an UPDATE statement with an ORDER BY clause. Update changes the records in a table, ORDER BY is usually used to order the records in a query set (e.g. after a SELECT statement) but not in the DB table itself.

What do you wish to achieve by using ORDER BY in this statement? Consider doing this instead:

```
UPDATE cds SET numberinstock = numberinstock + 3;

SELECT * FROM cds ORDER BY cdname asc
```